# how to select and display right row from a filtered jtable?

Tags: java, swing, filter, jframe, jtable

My code is that the user inputs the thing he wants to search about in a textfield and it is filtered automatically in the jtable but I have a function that when the user clicks on a row the data in the row is presented in a different Jframe. for example in the jtable I have row 1,2,3,4,5,6  the user filtered and the result was row 2 and 5 when i click in row '2' it will copy the data from the original row 1in the unfiltered table

this first part of code ith the function of the filtereing of my jtable from the textfield

```
    private void filter(String query){
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) History_Table.getModel();
        TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr=new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(model);
        History_Table.setRowSorter(tr);
        tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(query.trim()));
    
}
```

and this is the code for the row seletion and placing the data into the other jframe into their text areas

```
        private void History_TableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    
    int index = this.History_Table.getSelectedRow();
    TableModel model = History_Table.getModel();
    String name= model.getValueAt(index, 1).toString();
    String dov= model.getValueAt(index, 2).toString();
    String notes= model.getValueAt(index, 4).toString();
    String drugs= model.getValueAt(index, 5).toString();
    String diagnosis= model.getValueAt(index, 6).toString();
    
    jtRowData.setVisible(true);
    jtRowData.pack();
    jtRowData.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    jtRowData.nameA.setText(name);
    jtRowData.diagnosisA.setText(diagnosis);
    jtRowData.DateA.setText(dov);
    jtRowData.jTextArea2.setText(notes);
    jtRowData.DrugsA.setText(drugs);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int index = this.History_Table.getSelectedRow();
TableModel model = History_Table.getModel();
String name= model.getValueAt(index, 1).toString();
String dov= model.getValueAt(index, 2).toString();
String notes= model.getValueAt(index, 4).toString();
String drugs= model.getValueAt(index, 5).toString();
String diagnosis= model.getValueAt(index, 6).toString();
```

When a table is filtered (or sorted) the data in the model is not changed, only the data in the view is filtered (or sorted).

Therefore you need to map the currently selected row in the view to the row in the model:

```
int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel​( table.getSelectedRow() );
TableModel model = table.getModel();
String name= model.getValueAt(modelRow, 1).toString();
String dov= model.getValueAt(modelRow, 2).toString();
String notes= model.getValueAt(modelRow, 4).toString();
String drugs= model.getValueAt(modelRow, 5).toString();
String diagnosis= model.getValueAt(modelRow, 6).toString();
```